Dynamic JSON configuration for JavaScript libraries with injectable data through placeholders
I have a data flow through which I'll input new values into Chart.js or any other library. I need to use a JavaScript library in Blazor, such as Chart.js. For example:
const xValues = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000];
const yValues = [860,1140,1060,1060,1070,1110,1330,2210,7830,2478];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: xValues,
    datasets: [{
      data: yValues,
      borderColor: "red",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false}
  }
});

or
const xyValues = [
  {x:50, y:7},
  {x:60, y:8},
  {x:70, y:8},
  {x:80, y:9},
  {x:90, y:9},
  {x:100, y:9},
  {x:110, y:10},
  {x:120, y:11},
  {x:130, y:14},
  {x:140, y:14},
  {x:150, y:15}
];

new Chart("myChart", {
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
      data: xyValues
    }]
  },
  options:{...}
});

I would like to specify this configuration as a JSON text with placeholders for some data. For example:
{
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: @([$fieldX]),
    datasets: [{
      data: @([$fieldY]),
      borderColor: "red",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {display: false}
  }
}

Here @([$fieldX]) and @([$fieldY]) are placeholders, which means that the 'controller' should create an array variable, e.g., let var1 = [], and replace "@([$fieldX])" placeholder with this variable. Upon value injection, it should add new value $fieldX to the array , e.g. var1.add().
or
{
  type: "scatter",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      pointRadius: 4,
      pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,255,1)",
      data: @([{x: $fieldX, y: $fieldY}])
    }]
  },
  options:{...}
}

In this configuration, the placeholder @([{x: $fieldX, y: $fieldY}]) is intended to be replaced with a variable, such as let var2 = []. With each data injection, represented by {x: [fieldX value], y: [fieldY value]}, a new object containing the specified x and y values will be appended to var2.
This would allow me to configure any library simply by modifying the JSON configuration. My searches and queries to AI haven't yielded results. Are there any ready-made solutions or advice?
